# Are MySQL CASE statements prioritized?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm struggling with a query where there are some null values, and in my CASE statement, the test for the NULL values is not being processed. I've tried ordering the tests differently, but it doesn't seem to make a difference.

```
SELECT Title, library.LibraryID, Registered
FROM libraries
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT LibraryID,UserID,
        (CASE  
>>>                WHEN UserID IS NULL THEN "False"     <<<<<<<< PROBLEM
               WHEN UserID=1 THEN "YES! Registered" 
                   ELSE "Not Registered" 
     END) AS Registered
FROM librariesandmembers WHERE UserID=1) AS myAlias 
ON libraries.LibraryID = myAlias.LibraryID');
```

I've then tried a

```
WHEN USerID<>1 THEN "False"
```

But that doesn't change anything.

This is a PHP/MySQL app. The results in phpmyAdmin shows that the results of my query are producing NULLS where I want "False" to appear.

What am I missing? Must be something obvious but I just cannot see it.

[EDIT] Let me try explain the objective this way: I want to have a list of all (e.g. 5) libraries with the result next to it that the user is "Yes! Registered" or "Not Registered". There may or may not be a corresponding entry in librariesandmembers table. hence the NULL problem.

Comment: Try this CASE UserID WHEN NULL THEN "False" ?

Comment: @LeDuyKhanh `NULL` is **not** equal to `NULL`.

Comment: Have you tried your inner query by itself?

Comment: UserId will never be null in your derived table because you have a where clause that says it has to equal 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is your query:

```
SELECT Title, l.LibraryID, Registered
FROM libraries lLEFT JOIN 
      (SELECT LibraryID, UserID,
              (CASE WHEN UserID IS NULL THEN "False"     <<<<<<<< PROBLEM
                    WHEN UserID=1 THEN "YES! Registered" 
                   ELSE "Not Registered" 
               END) AS Registered
       FROM librariesandmembers
       WHERE UserID = 1
      ) AS myAlias 
      ON l.LibraryID = myAlias.LibraryID;
```

Within the subquery, `userId` always has the value of `1`, so the `case` statement only says `'YES! Registered'`.  You want to move that to the outer level.  To get the same effect, the condition `UserId=1` has to move to the `on` clause:

```
SELECT Title, l.LibraryID, Registered,
       (CASE WHEN myalias.UserID IS NULL THEN 'False'
             WHEN myalias.UserID = 1 THEN 'YES! Registered'
             ELSE 'Not Registered'
        END) AS Registered
FROM libraries l LEFT JOIN 
     librariesandmembers myalias
      ON l.LibraryID = myAlias.LibraryID and
         myalias.UserID = 1;
```

Comment: Solved. This answer got me thinking, and I approached it like this... My logic in three steps:  1) the inner level must produce a result that is only registered members whose id is 1. Let's say that matches only 3 valid rows out of the 500 in the table. The inner query is thus only 3 rows.     2) Now with a left join on libraries,  I want all libraries, say 47 of them. The join produces matching nulls where User 1 is not a member.     3) convert the NULLs to "False or something using the case statement n the outer level.       Hope that helps someone, and thanks everyone for the pointers.

Answer (score 1):

I'm almost certain this is to do with your join rather than your case statement. That is, you build your subquery result set with the switch to handle NULLs, then LOJ that to libraries, effectively creating wholly NULL records where no match exists. Thus your efforts with the Registered column are for naught. Try re-structuring your query like so:

```
SELECT 
  Title, 
  libraries.LibraryID, 
  (
    CASE
      WHEN librariesandmembers.UserID IS NOT NULL THEN "YES! Registered"
      ELSE "Not Registered"
    END
  ) as Registered
FROM 
  libraries LEFT JOIN librariesandmembers
    ON libraries.LibraryID = librariesandmembers.LibraryID
    AND librariesandmembers.UserID = 1
```

Also, you are handling the UserID=1 criterion twice. Your subquery effectively removes all other UserID's and therefore you have no need of the ELSE clause (which handles when the UserID is neither 1 or NULL). I think you could move my suggested WHERE clause to be a second JOIN condition, but I think this would get you the same results. Perhaps someone can argue for/against my approach?

Comment: Let me try explain the objective this way: I want to have a list of all (e.g. 5) libraries with the result next to it that the user is "Yes! Registered" or "Not Registered". There may or may not be a corresponding entry in librariesandmembers table. hence the NULL problem.

Comment: OK. Well, I think my suggestion will suffice. However, we can probably simplify it. Is the only reason to have a librariesandmembers record to indicate registration?

Comment: I've changed the switch slightly so there's now only one mention of the target UserID. The magic number can be swapped out for a variable or stored procedure parameter. This query should show all library records and report "YES! Registered" when a registration to that library exists for the target UserID and "Not Registered" when there is no match.

Comment: It certainly is a neater approach... but it only returns the two positive registrations. The nulls/not registered do not turn up in the results.

Comment: Ah! I think that's why I thought the WHERE condition needs to be a join condition.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
SELECT 
  Title, 
  libraries.LibraryID, 
  (
    CASE
      WHEN librariesandmembers.UserID IS Null OR librariesandmembers.UserID ='' THEN 'False'
      When librariesandmembers.UserID = 1 Then 'YES! Registered'
      ELSE "Not Registered"
    END
  ) as Registered
FROM 
  libraries LEFT JOIN librariesandmembers
    ON libraries.LibraryID = librariesandmembers.LibraryID
WHERE 
  librariesandmembers.UserID = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

How about

```
SELECT a.Title, a.LibraryID, IFNULL(myAlias.Registered,'Not Registered') Registered
FROM libraries a
     LEFT JOIN 
        (SELECT b.LibraryID, ('YES! Registered') Registered
         FROM librariesandmembers b
         WHERE b.UserID=1) AS myAlias  ON libraries.LibraryID = myAlias.LibraryID
```

Or this one

```
SELECT a.Title, 
       a.LibraryID, 
       IF((SELECT COUNT(*) 
           FROM librariesandmembers b
           WHERE b.LibraryID=a.LibraryID AND b.UserID=1)=0,'Not Registered','Yes! Registered') Registered
FROM libraries a
```

In your subquery there is only two posible values returned. The UserID or NULL when that user doesn't exists in members. That is why the CASE statement isn't working.